# Simplify with no calculator

Tags: arithmetic

$\dfrac{(8^3)(-16)^5}{4(-2)^8}$

$\dfrac{8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16}{4\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2}$

$\dfrac{8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16}{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2}$

$\dfrac{8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16\cdot-16}{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2}$

is it equal to... ?
$$
\dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2}
$$

I am bit confused, How can I handle this problem ?

Comment: Franck, noting the pattern of your last few questions, I offer a tiny tip: *factor anything that can be factored*. It helps a great deal in seeing what cancels.

Comment: Thanks ! Finally.. I understood. :)

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Just take everything to powers of 2 using the laws of exponents

$$\frac{8^3(-16)^5}{4(-2)^8}=\frac{-(2^3)^3(2^4)^5}{2^2\cdot2^8}=?$$

Comment: I don't like this.  It's really hard to get students to cancel before multiplying.  Often they see $\dfrac{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15}{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}$ and they start by multiplying out the numerator and the denominator!

Comment: @Michael Hardy:  to me it depends upon the problem.  For this one, especially without a calculator, all those powers of 2 scream at me and I would like an answer of -(2^n) as I know those (not quite this high).  I can do $5\cdot 4+3 \cdot 3-2-8$ in my head.

Answer (score 0):

**When multiplying fractions, cancel BEFORE multiplying.**

$$
\dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{8}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2} \cdot \dfrac{-16}{2}
$$

Wherever you see $\dfrac{8}{2}$, put $4$.

Wherever you see $\dfrac{-16}{2}$, put $-8$.

Then you have
$$
4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot(-8)\cdot(-8)\cdot(-8)\cdot(-8)\cdot(-8).
$$